# Create Checkbox for every Row in the Table with PHP and HTML. How can i call them in the PHP Section?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update, tinyint

[image]
EDIT: Here is the SQL SELECT

```
$statement = $db->prepare("
    SELECT A.Vorname
         , A.Nachname
         , O.IndexcardRight
         , O.QuizRight
         , O.Admin_AdminID
      FROM Admin A
      LEFT 
      JOIN AdminOfModule O
        ON O.Admin_AdminID = A.AdminID
     WHERE O.AdminTyp = 'Student'
     GROUP 
        BY A.AdminID
");

$statement->execute();
$admin = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $statement->rowCount();
```

Here is the PHP and HTML Code with the Update SQL
which doenst work for sure because i have no unique id's

i tried some stuff like give in the name or id quiz[] but i cannot call it in the php function. And couldnt find much ways to do it.

```
<form method="post">
    <?php
        $i = 2;
        $y = 2;

        foreach ($admin as $row) {
            $aii = $row['Admin_AdminID'];
            $i++;
            $y++;

            echo '<label>' . $row["Vorname"] . $row["Nachname"] . '</label>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<label> Quiz</label>';
            //echo'<input type="hidden>"';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="quiz' . $i . '" id="quiz' . $i . '"> ';
            echo '';
            echo '<label> Indexcard</label>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="indexcard' . $i . '" id="indexcard' . $i . '">';
            echo '<br>';
            //quizx indexcardx wenn button geklickt und wenn quizx isset dann update table adminofmodule set quizright =1 where
        }

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            //$ic = $_POST["indexcard$i"];
            //$q = $_POST["quiz$i"];

            if (isset($_POST["quiz$i"])) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE AdminOfModule SET QuizRight = 1 WHERE '$aii' = '$i' ");
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            else {
                $stmt1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE AdminOfModule SET QuizRight = 0 WHERE '$aii' = '$i' ");
                $stmt1->execute();
            }

            if (isset($_POST["indexcard$i"])) {
                $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE AdminOfModule SET IndexcardRight = 1 WHERE'$aii' = '$i'");
                $stmt2->execute();
            }
            else {
                $stmt3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE AdminOfModule SET IndexcardRight = 0 WHERE'$aii' = '$i' ");
                $stmt3->execute();
            }
        }

        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">';
    ?>
</form>
```

The Problem is, if i check the Checkbox at the first rows it will stand 0 but if click the last Checkbox it sets all to 1.

Comment: Why do you set the iteration variables `$i++` and `$y++` before using it the first time?

Comment: i know it's not the best way but im getting the 'right' num's at the end . The id's are begining with 3.

Comment: Could you fix it already?

Comment: no im struggling

Comment: Can you post the $row array?

Comment: u can look up, i posted it in the first row